# Почему не реализуются override итераторы в производных классах

Tags: c#, ооп

Здравствуйте
Задавал уже вопрос практически с этим же кодом, но другой проблемой, которую удалось успешно решить, посему обращаюсь за помощью во второй раз.
У меня в программе есть 4 класса:

Базовый Figure:

```
    class Figure 
    {
        private List<Figure> figures = new List<Figure>();

        public void Add(Figure f)
        {
            figures.Add(f);
        }

       public string coords = "";
        public virtual void getCoords() { }

        public virtual IEnumerable myItr()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                yield return "there are must be coords";
            }
        }

        public static int X;
        public static int Y;
        public static int Z;
        public  double SideSize;
        public string Name;
    }
```

И производные, Round:

```
    class Round : Figure
    {
        public override IEnumerable myItr()
        {

            yield return this.coords;
        }

        public Round(int sideSize, int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            SideSize = sideSize;
            //getPerimeter();
           getCoords();
        }
    }
```

Cube и Line идентичны классу round

В основной программе при чтении с файла в цикле создаются объекты с разными параметрами.

Содержимое файла:

```
round 10 2 3 round 5 4 6 round 3 5 -1 cube 4 -3 -2 3 cube 3 3 5 -2 cube 7 6 8 9 line 1 1 2 line 6 7 4 line 19 4 9
```

сама программа:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("File.txt");
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] figuresParam = text.Split(' ');

        List<Round> rounds = new List<Round>();
        List<Cube> cubes = new List<Cube>();
        List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

        for (int i = 0, j = 0, c = 0, l = 0, r = 0; i < figuresParam.Length; i += 4, j += 1)
        {
            if (figuresParam[i] == "round")
            {
                rounds.Add(new Round(Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i+1]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i + 2]), Convert.ToInt32(figuresParam[i+3])));
                rounds[r].Name = "round";
                r++;
            }//Аналогично к первому еще два таких же if
        }

        Figure figures = new Figure();

        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            figures.Add(lines[i]);
            a++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rounds.Count; i++)
        {
            figures.Add(rounds[i]);
            a++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Count; i++)
        {
            figures.Add(cubes[i]);
            a++;
        }

        foreach (string s in figures.myItr())
        { Console.WriteLine(s); }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

В foreach должны(по моей логике) реализоваться индивидуальные для каждого производного класса итераторы, но исполняется только этот же итератор в основном классе. По какой причине так происходит?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите из кода все, что не относится к проблеме и поправьте форматировние. Очень сложно читать. Нужен [mcve]

Comment: В причине закрытия акцент на словах «минимальный код».

Comment: "но почему-то исполняется только этот же итератор в основном классе." -  как ты пришел к этому выводу?

Comment: пошаговый дебаг и вывод в консоли показали что всё именно так как я описал

Comment: @АртёмКичигин: Уменьшите код до **реального минимума**, воспроизводящего проблему. У вас 4 класса в иерархии — они нужны все 4, или достаточно двух для того, чтобы показать проблему? У вас есть методы наподобие `getPerimeter` — они важны для этого вопроса, или проблема останется, если их убрать? Чем меньше у вас лишнего кода, тем больше шансы на хороший ответ от опытного участника. Это, кстати, в ваших же интересах.

Comment: @VladD: Постарался минимизировать как можно сильнее, оставив 2 класса без лишних методов.

Comment: Ты обратился к "myItr" объекта "figures", а он типа "Figure".  Тебе же нужно получить доступ к СПИСКУ "figures" в классе "Figure" и перебирать его. Тогда будет работать.

Comment: @ValeraKvip: Как это сделать?
единственное, на что хватило моих способностей, это слегка изменить код внутри итератора:
`for (int i = 0; i < figures.Count(); i++)
            {
               yield return figures[i].coords;
            }`
но проблему с бездействием итератора в производном классе это не решает

Comment: У вас там гора проблем. У вас неправильная иерархия объектов (список фигур не должен быть базовой фигурой, т. к., например, квадрат не является списком фигур). Статические поля — вторая ошибка. Ну и метод  `Figure.myItr()` должен, судя по всем, выглядеть так: `foreach (var f in figures) { foreach (var obj in f.myItr()) yield return obj; }`.